# How to ( Unable) to squash commits using rebase interactive in source tree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to squash commits so that my repo history is not littered with unimportant commits like "minor fix 1", "minor fix 2".. and so on. But I seem unable to do it using sourcetree UI.

I made a number of commits with self-descriptive names such as "A major part of the work", "minor fix", "fix 2" ( not yet pushed to remote). And of course I want to squash all these 3 commits into a proper commits such as "do feature a2a".
[image]

The first step is I click on "rebase children interactively on the previous commits", and then I try to rearrange the commits so that they represent the logical order I want them to be in. In my case here, I arrange them so that all the minor fixes are subsumed under a major commit, and arranged in chronological order, and of course I also edit the commit message to make it clearer, as shown below per the instruction [here](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/sourcetree/interactive-rebase-sourcetree):

[image]

Then I click OK, but then, I got this message (**MERGING CONFLICT**):

[image]

I've no idea why there is a merge conflict? How to fix it? Is there anyway to get the squash commits working properly using sourcetree UI alone ( without using the git command line)?

Comment: I believe that you will have merge commit by doing squash from git command line also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess now I figure out how it works:

1. Make sure that the squashed commits must be arranged in reversed chronological order, ie: the latest one on the top, not on the bottom.
2. When click OK, make sure that the `Amend Commit?` column is not ticked. One can edit the commit comment before and tick the `Amend Commit?` column, but not when one is prepared to click on the `OK` button.
3. And more importantly, **you can't start your new commit message with `#`**. If you must label your commit starting with bug number (eg: `#1234`), you might want to append a few white spaces in front of `#` (eg:    `#1234`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to squash the commits together anyway, don't rearrange their order -- changing the order is what causes the conflicts.

The end content of the commit will be exactly the same, and in your case you want to reword the message anyway.

---

From the command line, with this history :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
* 7f6cc32 (HEAD -> master) fix 2
* 11adfe2 minor fix
* 871c26d A major part of the work
* 59a2b18 really new beginning
* e6872a9 Merge branch 'master' into xxx
...
```

If I run `git rebase --interactive e6872a9`, I first get to edit a file, with the following content :

```
pick 59a2b18 really new beginning
pick 871c26d A major part of the work
pick 11adfe2 minor fix
pick 7f6cc32 fix 2

# Rebase e6872a9..7f6cc32 onto 7f6cc32 (4 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
...
```

The idea here is to indicate what action I want to apply to each commit (keep it, squash it with its predecessor, edit it ...), save & exit, then git will replay the commits one after the other, and apply the action I chose.

Two remarks :

- when you inspect the history of a branch, you usually get the *most recent commits* first, but in this file the list has the *oldest commits* first (the reverse of what `git log` shows by default) ;
- if I edit a line to say `squash`, the commit will be combined with the commit *from the line above* (the previous commit).

So : if I wanted to combine commits `fix 2`, `minor fix` and `A major part of the work` together, I would edit the file to :

```
pick 59a2b18 really new beginning
pick 871c26d A major part of the work
squash 11adfe2 minor fix
squash 7f6cc32 fix 2

# Rebase e6872a9..7f6cc32 onto 7f6cc32 (4 commands)
...
```

then save & exit.

When you use `squash`, it turns out `git` asks you to edit the commit message anyway, so I don't need to change some other action to `edit` or `reword`.

---

I have no experience with Sourcetree, but I suspect the order of the commits in the list is the same as in the file's ("reverse" order, oldest commit first).

Just do not alter that order, and apply `[Squash with previous]` on each of the two commits `minor fix` and `fix 2`.

Comment: I see your point now.. the moment I rearrange the message so that the top commit is the latest one, this problem goes away, but it replaces with other message, which I will ask as another question.